# What is the difference between the network adapter receive bandwidth and the used bandwidth

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, bandwidth, resource-monitor

I was downloading huge files (a game on Steam), and I was wondering why my download speed was not exceeding 5MB/s, on my 5GHz Wi-Fi behind FttB.

So I opened the Task Manager on the Performance tab, and the resource monitor. I was surprised to find a big difference between the two:

- The Task Manager shows a "Receive" bandwidth of 70MB/s for my Wi-Fi interface.
- The resource monitor shows Steam downloading at 5MB/s, and a few other process and services downloading 20KB/s or less. The total is far from 50MB/s. In "TCP Connections", no packets are dropped.

So where does the difference come from? I do not have a Rootkit downloading at 60MB/s, do I?
I am far from my Wi-Fi AP, so I would not be surprised if some Wi-Fi packets would be dropped. How can I find out?

Comment: Does Task Manager really show you _megabytes_ per second?

Comment: Hum, good point. It shows Mbits/s. This explains that. Thanks!